# Why does this menu move in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, nav

I am creating a page (linked below) and am using the HTML5 tag, `nav`. However, if the window is resized in Google Chrome, the menu jumps to below the `div.banner`.

Why is this happening and how can I fix it?

Here is the page I'm designing: http://ubuntuone.com/1O7MLCGfZ0EqxQSFlpy4Yr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**CSS**

add the following css styles to a.brand at line no. 71 and line no. 343

```
a.brand {
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

add the following css styles to header at line no. 125 and line no. 397

```
header{
 clear:both;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work for you:

on line-363:

```
            nav {
    height: 50px;
    width: 400px; /* 5x the length of each nav item */
position:absolute;     /* use positioning rather than "float:right;" */
top:0px;
right:0px;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    color: #004824;
    background: #fff;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

and on line-331:

```
        div.banner {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    z-index: 2;        /* change z-index so img will be on top */
    border-bottom: 1px solid #004824;
}
```

Here is a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/apaul34208/Ns5sU/6/) that may help demonstrate.